# Javascript code is driving me crazy, syntax error?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code and it says unexpected token `<`, but all the `<` signs are in the right place.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
  var scores = [84, 99, 91, 65, 87, 55, 72, 68, 95, 42], 
  topScorers = [], scoreLimit = 90;

  for (i=0; i<=scores.length; i++)
  {
    if (scores[i]>scoreLimit)
    {
      <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">topScorers.push(scores</span>[i]);
    }
  }

  <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">console.log(topScorers</span>);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"but all the < signs are in the right palce"` no they're not, you can't have markup in the script tabs like that

Comment: Totally random and not helpful, but actually, this would be valid JS. `span = Hello = World = end = 1; Hello <span>World<span> end`

Answer (score 3):

You can't create HTML elements in javascript by doing `<span></span>`.

If you want to create HTML elements use the `createElement` function.

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'skimlinks-unlinked';
```

Now you can fill this with whatever info you want and then append it to the body.

```
span.innerHTML = scores[i];
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/vumehibabo/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: The `skimlinks-unlinked` spans come from a broken code formatting, OP doesn’t actually want those but just copy/pasted broken code from somewhere else.

Comment: Ah, okay, well. I guess there's no harm in showing how to add the class anyway :) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple `<span>` tags in your `<script />` section that should not be there.

This is not PHP: if you want to manipulate the DOM with JavaScript, then insert / append elements to it.

I would recommend using a JavaScript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as it facilitates DOM manipulations a lot.
Example in jQuery:

```
$("body").append('<span class="skimlinks-unlinked">' + topScorers[i] + '</span>');
```

Comment: Even in PHP, you can’t just have in-line HTML code like that.

Comment: It's true, but from what the OP does, it looks to me that he/she has a PHP background where you can echo html tags.

Comment: You may think that, but those `skimlinks-unlinked` are because of copy/pasting from bad sources. OP didn’t write that code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are mixing HTML markup within JavaScript code blocks. As soon as you’re inside `<script> … </script>`, the rules of JavaScript apply, and there, these characters are invalid.

Those `skimlinks-unlinked` things are part of a broken code formatter on some Wordpress sites. So you likely copy/pasted code from somewhere without knowing what it meant, expecting it to work. Unfortunately, the code formatter added stuff that broke the code. If you remove that markup, the code should work as expected:

```
<script>
var scores = [84, 99, 91, 65, 87, 55, 72, 68, 95, 42], 
    topScorers = [], scoreLimit = 90;

for (i=0; i<=scores.length; i++)
{
  if (scores[i]>scoreLimit)
  {
    topScorers.push(scores[i]);
  }
}

console.log(topScorers);
</script>
```

For some background information, “skimlinks” seems to be an advertising plugin for Wordpress sites (one of those pesky ones that automatically link some buzzwords), and it incorrectly did that within code blocks too, breaking the code. You can read a bit more about that problem [here](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/skimlinks-messed-up-inside-code-tags-an-actual-error).